# Is there any way to trigger a function when prefetfcing is done in Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am quite new to front-end development and I am sorry if this is a damn question.

I am using Gatsby project to create my web site.
In this web site, I have multiple pages and one of the pages adds content to an element after its page is created.

For this, I use something like below.

```
useEffect(() => {
    addView()
    return () => {
        console.log("unmounted");
    }
}, [])
```

This works as expected. However, `addView()` function takes a lot of time to load so I would like to preload this when users arrive the home page.

I assume I can achieve something like this by triggering `addView()` after gatsby prefetches the page instead of using `useEffect()`. But I am not sure how I can know when gatsby prefetch is done.

So my question is, is there any way to trigger a function when prefetch is done and a certain element is created in another page?

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part of your `addView()` function is that you need the DOM tree to be rendered in order to populate your element, that's why the `useEffect` indeed.

Said that, you can check the [Gatsby Browser APIs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/) to see if there's anyone that fit's your requirements. However, in the `gatsby-browser.js` file you will be outside the React's lifecycle so it will be difficult to guess how the code will behave.

I don't know if it's an option for your use-case but the optimal solution would be to populate and fill (what `addView()` does) in [Gatsby fetching methods](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/data-fetching/).

Alternatively, you can try to trigger your `addView()` function only if the element is empty and removing the unmount:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(element.current.length > 0){ // or any other validation like checking if it has children
       addView()
    }
}, [])
```

Assuming that you are using `useRef` hook (that's why the `.current`) to get the element to be filled. With this approach, you will only trigger the function once.